# React hook form submit on cancel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook form. I have a button cancel with a OnCancel function. Basically React Hook Form auto submit on cancel. Why ? is there a way to block the submit on cancel ?

```
    const onCancel = () => {
    history.goBack();
};


<StyledButton onClick={onCancel}>
    {Translate('cancel')}
</StyledButton>
```

Comment: It's likely because you're using a button. Try giving it a prop of `type="button"`?

Comment: @Marizona Your question makes no sense. Specifically the "Why?" question. Why what? What are you asking why about? I'm guessing there is a language barrier here and you're missing some verb tense and plurality in the previous question? I suggest asking a friend or colleague to proofread your question and re-write it because I don't understand what the question is. (I'm US American and read & write American English.)

Comment: Also, not to be picky, but more so meticulous, which I think is important in posting code and questions about the code: your question uses text OnCancel with a capital O, whereas your code below it uses a lowercase `o` in `const onCancel`, so it is questionable which OnCancel you are referring to, the Button or the function.

Answer (score 4):

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const dontSubmit = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Dont submit this');
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>


      <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="button" onClick={dontSubmit}>Do not submit!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can either give your button the property `type="button"` see example code. Or you can add `e.preventDefault()` to your function. See the commented code.